# Unusual find results with execv

Tags: c, linux, find, exec

```
if (pid == 0) {
    char * para[] = {"find", "./", "*.c", NULL};
    execv("/usr/bin/find", para);
    printf("execu failed: %s\n", strerror(errno)); //ls -l -R
    exit(-1);
}
```

When I try to use find from `execv()` I get the message `./: ‘*.c’: No such file or directory`.  When I run the `execv(find...)` without the `*.c` arugument I get the contents of the folder my program is compiled in, including a number of .c files `./test.c, ./rock_paper_scissors.c, ./main.c` among other things.  When I run the command `find ./ *.c` directly in terminal I get the expected results, all of the .c files in that directory.

Is there some different way that I am required to use find via exec that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Try `find . -name .*c` in your C code.

Comment: BTW, in your shell command `find ./ *.c`, the wildcard pattern `*.c` will be expanded by your shell first, and the result will be passed to `find` as its arguments.

Comment: @LeeDuhem: There is no shell involved when using `exec*()` on the command directly.

Comment: @alk I know, what I meant is when he run the command in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
char * para[] = {"find", "./", "*.c", NULL};
```

to be

```
char * para[] = {"find", "./", "-name", "*.c", NULL};
```

From [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> -name *pattern*
>
> Base of file name (the path with the leading directories
>        removed) matches shell pattern pattern.  Because the leading
>                 directories are removed, the file names considered for a match
>      with **-name** will never include a slash, so `-name a/b` will
>     never match anything (you probably need to use -path instead).